# How to correctly perform partial updates in Gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have some sort of virtual file system. List of folders, each folder contains files, and ACL.
So structure looks like this:

```
type Model struct {
    ID        uint       `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
}

type User struct {
    Model
    Name string
}

type Folder struct {
    Model
    Name string
}

type File struct {
    Model
    Name string
    FolderID      uint
    Folder        Folder
    Acl           []User `json:"acl" gorm:"many2many:file_acl"`
}
```

It comes from frontend as full fledged JSON. It gets demarshalled.
What happens next when I call `Save(&file)` it correctly stores File, creates record inside `file_acl`.

Also it updates Folder and Users.

Here comes my question - how to skip those dependent updates but retain autogenerated queries to update/insert into `file_acl` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent cascade updates you should use `association_autoupdate` option.

```
Db.Set("gorm:association_autoupdate", false).Save(&file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want `db.Set("gorm:save_associations", false).Save(...)`

Comment: It solves one problem but immediately brings another one - `file_acl` is not getting updated now.

Comment: This is tricky - from one side I want to update File and its metadata (list of users who has access to file) but from the other side just store references to User and Folder.